# Can a spreadsheet (with format an everything) , be attached to a sidebar of another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a calendario asignacion Tools that works with sheets.

I have already make it work but I want to know if it is possible to attach a whole spreadsheets into a sidebar of the spreadsheets of the assignation tool.

Comment: A Spreadsheet sidebar is created using Google HTMLService and is formatted using HTML.  So you can not directly show another spreadsheet as a sidebar but depending on the amount of data you want to display you could construct a sidebar.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What do you mean by attach a spreadsheet to a sidebar? Are you talking about embedding it in a similar way that spreadsheet could be embedded in any website ? Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: If the embedded spreadsheet is public, maybe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.